# How Do I Install Themes In Cinnamon?

Tags: configuration, cinnamon, home, theme

I downloaded a couple of themes for Cinnamon but I don't know how to install them. The website I went to said:

> To install a theme: Download it and decompress it in ~/.themes.

I type `~/.themes` into the terminal and I get this below.

What am I doing wrong?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: try making the directory first: `mkdir ~/.themes` and then decompress a theme into that directory.

Comment: Please don't take screenshots of text. Copy-paste the text.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, thanks to user1794469, I found out how to do it.

You just make a file in the home directory called ".themes"

Putting the "." before the letters makes the file hidden,so when you want to decompress (extract) your theme into it's respective folder, you have to click "Enter Location" in your archive or zip manager. and simply type in ".themes" as the location for the file to be placed and installed accordingly.

Then finally you can go to the themes on your desktop and apply it in all its glory.